# Creating JWT-Signed HTTP Request in Android App with User's Google Play Identity

Tags: android, jwt, google-play-developer-api

In my Android app, I have not implemented my own authentication mechanism.  Instead, I rely on the Google Play user mechanism.

The app needs to connect to a back-end to obtain user data, report user information, etc.  The back-end is implemented as a REST endpoint.  I would like requests to the REST endpoint to be signed with a JWT based on the Google Play user's credentials.

Is this possible?